# Divide by Zero error Encountered for simple select statement

Tags: sql-server, dividebyzeroexception

I am trying to run simple select query but its returning "Divide by Zero error Encountered"

```
select * from RL1
```

and this returns Divide by Zero error Encountered

Can anyone please help me resolve it?

The View Schema as under:

```
GO
CREATE VIEW pms.RL1 AS
    SELECT        rv2.ID, rv2.DS, CASE WHEN rv2.LR / ISNULL(NULLIF (rv2.LR, 0), 1) > 4 THEN 1000 * rv4.LR ELSE 1000 * rv2.LR END AS LR, CASE WHEN rv2.RR / ISNULL(NULLIF (rv2.RR, 0),
                              1) > 4 THEN 1000 * rv4.RR ELSE 1000 * rv2.RR END AS RR
    FROM            (SELECT        IDRV, ID, DS, IDRC, LR, LO, RR, RO, LW, LO
                              FROM            dbo.RV
                              WHERE        (IDRC = 2)) AS rv2 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                                 (SELECT        IDRutValue, ID, DS, IDRC, LR, LO, RR, RO, LW, LO
                                   FROM            dbo.RV
                                   WHERE        (IDRC = 4)) AS rv4 ON rv2.ID = rv4.ID AND rv2.DS = rv4.DS
```

Comment: That is not a "table". See how words matter?

Comment: Check the division operation in your view query. It didn't handle cases where the denominator is zero

Comment: @Squirrel: How could this "ISNULL(NULLIF (rv2.LR, 0), 1)" be zero?